# Does getPastLogs require arvhived parity node?

Tags: parity, logs

Talking about parity here:

```
--pruning=[METHOD]
    Configure pruning of the state/storage trie. METHOD may be one of auto, archive, fast: archive - keep all state
    trie data. No pruning. fast - maintain journal overlay. Fast but 50MB used. auto - use the method most recently
    synced or default to fast if none synced. (default: auto)
```

And I use web3.eth.getPastLogs to query old logs.

Do I need to use "archive" node in oder to get all information about past logs?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need pruning archive as this is only giving you information of the state of the blockchain for older blocks, this has no influence on the logs, which you are interested in.

Comment: Is this answer up to date? From my experience, it seems you would need archive node to do getPastLogs, otherwise the node is giving empty past logs.